# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in .net core

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-core, foreign-keys

I have two model class as;

```
  public class MessageDetailModel
{
    [Key]
    public int messageDetailsId { get; set; }
    public MessageModel messageModel { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
    public int senderId { get; set; }
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
 
}
```

and

```
public class MessageModel
{
    [Key]
    public int messageId { get; set; }
    public int senderId { get; set; } 
    public int customId { get; set; }
    public bool ReadInfo { get; set; }
    public  virtual List<MessageDetailModel> MessageDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and it is my context class ;

```
 public virtual DbSet<MessageDetailModel> messageDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MessageModel> messages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PersonModel> persons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DirectoryModel> directory { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get messageId over MessageDetailModel but messageId returns as 0 and I have that error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
 Console.WriteLine(k.messageModel.messageId); //( k is my var which gets from messagedetail model)
```

How can ı reach messageId over MessadeDetailModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current link between your two models that would represent a Foreign Key.

You'd need to do something like this for your model if you want a Foreign Key to link to the related object:

```cs
public class MessageDetailModel
{
    [Key]
    public int messageDetailsId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("messageId")] // Added Data Annotation for the Foreign Key relationship
    public MessageModel messageModel { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
    public int senderId { get; set; }
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int messageId { get; set; } // This would be your Foreign Key
}
```

I've added the `messageId` column to your MessageDetailModel to match the Primary Key column of your MessageModel as that's necessary for the link to form.

You would use the `[ForeignKey("messageId")]` Data Annotation above the variable for the `MessageModel` to determine what value it needs to use when finding the object you want.